# Polymer Adding a behavior to a element

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I've created a new Polymer Project.

via terminal `mkdir project; cd project; polymer init;` Then create a application drawer template.

Whats the correct way to add a behavior to the my-view2 element in 
`src/my-view2.html`?

If I create a behaviour at `src/some-behavior.html`

```
<script>
SomeBehavior = {
    testing: function()
    { alert('hello'); }
}
</script>
```

Then importing it in view2

`<link rel="import" href="some-behavior.html">`

and including it in polymer

```
Polymer({

  is: 'my-view2',

  behaviors: [SomeBehavior]

});
```

and adding a button to the the html to invoke the new function i've just created.

`<button on-tap="testing">Test</button>`

Then building the polymer application via

`sudo polymer build # im using sudo because my permissions are wrong`

Then deploying the `build/bundled` directory to firebase with

`sudo firebase deploy # same dodgy permission problem`

This will work on Desktop:
I've checked with Chrome, Firefox and Safari all with the most uptodate version.

But on iOS I run into a problem with the view2 page not loading. I've tested on iPhone osx 9.3 (I think, most uptodate version anyway) then in a emulator with iPhone 4s, 5s, 6s

If I remove the behavior from the page, rebuild and deploy, it goes back to working.

If I run a polymer lint I get this warning

`Behavior SomeBehavior not found when mixing properties into my-view2!`

I'm I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Polymer Project Documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors), you'll need to define your own namespace in your behavior html file like so:

```
window.MyBehaviors = window.MyBehaviors || {};
MyBehaviors.SomeBehavior = { ... }
```

This adds a MyBehaviors namespace to the global window object, so the behavior can be referenced from your element as "myBehaviors.SomeBehavior".

I believe Polymer requires this to avoid collisions with current and future Polymer behaviors.

Also see [Rob Dodson's video on Behaviors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrlmieL3Z0k).